# How to log wkhtmltopdf command output to file on Windows?

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd, stdout, io-redirection

I'm trying to log the output of the wkhtmltopdf EXE to a file however the log file it creates is just blank lines with no actual output. I can see the output in the CMD window but the file the command is redirected to is blank.

```
C:\PROGRA~1\wkhtmltopdf\bin\wkhtmltopdf >> C:\test.txt
```

In the CMD window I see the documentation for wkhtmltopdf, like the below:

> Name:
> wkhtmltopdf 0.12.5 (with patched qt)
>
> Synopsis:
> wkhtmltopdf [GLOBAL OPTION]... [OBJECT]...

but the output file has 16 blank lines?

I've tried various alternative ways of running the command, using cmd /c or the START command, tried with powershell as well but have had no joy so far.

Any help with this would be much appreciated, thank you!

Comment: What does the output normally look like when not redirected? If some output is going to stderr, then you can use `wkhtmltopdf > log.txt 2>&1` for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this by changing the command as follows, thanks to Cpt.Whale comment for pointing me in the right direction!

```
C:\PROGRA~1\wkhtmltopdf\bin\wkhtmltopdf 1>> C:\test.txt 2>&1
```